# How to go from finite to infinitesimal form of the Fubini-Study metric?

Tags: state-space-geometry, metrics, fubini-study-metric

As mentioned *e.g.* in [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric), given a pair of pure states $\psi,\phi\in\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}$, the geodesic distance between them is
$$\gamma(\psi,\phi) = \arccos\sqrt{\frac{\langle\psi|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle\langle\phi|\phi\rangle}},$$
while the corresponding infinitesimal form, obtained taking $\phi=\psi+\delta\psi$, reads
$$ds^2 = \frac{\langle \delta\psi|\delta\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle} - \frac{\langle\delta\psi|\psi\rangle \langle\psi|\delta\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle^2}.$$

This should be a simpler case of the more general calculation for the Bures metric discussed in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18349/55), while a related discussion is also found [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12756/55).
What's a direct way to perform this calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Quite amusingly, I just realised pretty much this exact question [was previously asked on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2110467/173147), and an answer was given there a few years ago... by myself. I completely forgot. I'll copy-paste the answer I gave there and keep the post up for future reference.

---

Start by considering the following identities, obtained via basic complex algebra and Taylor expansions:
$$|\langle \psi,\psi+\delta\psi\rangle|^2
= \|\psi\|^4\left\lvert 1+ \frac{\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle}{\|\psi\|^2}\right\rvert^2 
= \|\psi\|^4 \left(1 +\frac{2\operatorname{Re}\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle}{\|\psi\|^2} + \frac{|\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle|^2}{\|\psi\|^4}\right)$$

$$
\|\psi+\delta\psi\|^2=\|\psi\|^2 + \|\delta\psi\|^2 + 2\operatorname{Re}\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle
$$

$$
\frac{1}{\|\psi+\delta\psi\|^2}\simeq\frac{1}{\|\psi\|^2} \left(
1
- \frac{2\operatorname{Re}\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle}{\|\psi\|^2}
- \frac{\|\delta\psi\|^2}{\|\psi\|^2} + \frac{4[\operatorname{Re}\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle]^2}{\|\psi\|^4}
\right)
$$

$$
\arccos\sqrt{1-x} \simeq \sqrt x, \quad\text{for } x\to 0^+.
$$

---

Our goal is to compute the quantity
$$\gamma(\psi,\psi+\delta\psi) = \arccos\sqrt{\frac{|\langle \psi,\psi+\delta\psi\rangle|^2}{\|\psi\|^2 \|\psi+\delta\psi\|^2} }.$$

Assuming $\|\psi\|^2=1$ for simplicity (we can keep the $\|\psi\|$ terms around but nothing substantial changes in the expressions) we have
$$
\frac{\lvert\langle\psi,\psi+\delta\psi\rangle\rvert^2}{\|\psi+\delta\psi\|^2}
\simeq 1 + \lvert\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle\rvert^2 - \|\delta\psi\|^2,
$$
therefore
$$
\gamma(\psi,\psi+\delta\psi)\simeq\arccos\sqrt{1+\lvert\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle\rvert^2-\|\delta\psi\|^2}
\simeq \sqrt{\|\delta\psi\|^2-\lvert\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle\rvert^2},
$$
and finally
$$
ds^2 \equiv \gamma(\psi,\psi+\delta\psi)^2 \simeq \|\delta\psi\|^2-\lvert\langle\psi,\delta\psi\rangle\rvert^2,
$$
which is the expression we were looking for.